# Prerequisites for understanding algebraic geometry of “algebraic gerbes”

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, stacks, algebraic-stacks, gerbes

I am trying to learn about algebraic geometry of [gerbes](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06QB).

I am familiar with set up of gerbes in the case of differential geometry. Though there is some similarity between differentiable gerbes and gerbes as mentioned above, they are not quite same.

So, what are the prerequisites to learn about gerbes in the algebraic geometry set up? I am familiar with notion of stacks. What other Grothendieck topologies and stacks over categories with that Grothendieck topologies should I be comfortable with to understand and use the notion of gerbe mentioned above.

Comment: I am not sure there is much algebraic geometry specifically about gerbes. The subjects where this notion really matters are related to Tannaka theory or to non-abelian cohomology.

Comment: @Niels Thanks for your comment. I am not at all familiar with Tannaka theory and know one or two things about non abelian cohomology... can you please give some references (not the obvious ones that I would get on google search :)) about Tannaka theory and non-abelian cohomology

Comment: Very roughly speaking, gerbes arising from commutative groups are controlled by the second etale cohomology, in particular for $\mu_n$ one asks about $n$-torsion in the Brauer group. Etale cohomology and the Brauer group are generally more elementary topics than gerbes themselves, and understanding these well would probably be helpful for working with gerbes.

Comment: Thankw for your comment.. How much Etale cohomology or Brauer Groups should one understand before understanding gerbe (over scheme)? Do you have any preference for book about Etalr cohomology or. Brauer groups?

Comment: Standard references for etale cohomology and Brauer groups are Milne's book (Etale cohomology) and lecture notes from his webpage.